# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::whithPivot() laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

Mi problema está así, tengo una tabla `subjects` que tiene una relación muchos a muchos con una tabla de `teachers` usando una tabla intermedia `subjectteacher`, pero cuando quiero usar esta relación me sale el error de que la función `whithPivot` no esta definida pero tengo una relación uno a muchos que funciona bien, así que no se en donde pueda estar el problema.

El modelo de **Subject:**

```html
/**
    * The teachers that belong to the subject.
    */
    public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Teacher','subjects_teachers')
                    ->whithPivot('teachers_id');
    }
```

El modelo de **Teacher:**

```html
/**
     * The subjects that belong to the teacher.
     */
    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Subject','subjects_teachers')
                    ->whithPivot('subjects_id');
    }
```

y el modelo que tiene ambos id:

```html
class SubjectTeacher extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'subjects_teachers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idSubjectsTeachers';
    protected $fillable = ['subjects_id','teachers_id'];
}
```

Para hacer la prueba y ver si se obtienen los datos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```html
$teachers = Teacher::find(1);
$subjects = $teachers->subjects()->get();
dd($subjects);
```

Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nombre de la función es **withPivot**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Corregi ese error gracias, ahora al hacerlo me sale este otro 1054 Unknown column 'teacher_idTeacher' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `subjects_teachers` where `teacher_idTeacher` = 1) , se a lo que se refiere pero no se como solucionarlo, o como decirle a laravel que mi llave es teacher_id.

Comment: @SantiD aquí tienes la [documentación](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method___construct) puedes ver como tienes los argumentos string $foreignPivotKey, string $relatedPivotKey para especificar tus columnas